# "Unfortunately, *meu aplicativo* has stopped" na passagem de dados para Activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, intent

Estou fazendo um app que formata referências bibliográficas de acordo com a ABNT, mas está havendo um erro para passar os dados digitados pelo usuário para a próxima `activity`, que exibe os dados formatados.

Segue os códigos e o print com a mensagem de erro.

```
public class LivroTela extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.campos_livro);

        setupbotaoGerarLivro(); 
    }

    private void setupbotaoGerarLivro() {
        Button btnGerarLivro = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGerarLivro);
        btnGerarLivro.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {       
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(LivroTela.this, FormatacaoLivro.class);
                EditText etAutor1= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etAutor1);
                String autor1 = etAutor1.getText().toString();
                intent.putExtra("etAutor1", autor1);

                EditText etAutor2= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etAutor2);
                String autor2 = etAutor2.getText().toString();
                intent.putExtra("etAutor2", autor2);

                EditText etAutor3= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etAutor3);
                String autor3 = etAutor3.getText().toString();
                intent.putExtra("etAutor3", autor3);

                EditText etTitulo1= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etTitulo1);
                String titulo1 = etTitulo1.getText().toString();
                intent.putExtra("etTitulo1", titulo1);

                EditText etEdicao= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etEdicao);
                String edicao1 = etEdicao.getText().toString();
                intent.putExtra("etEdicao", edicao1);

                EditText etCidade= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etCidade);
                String cidade1 = etCidade.getText().toString();
                intent.putExtra("etCidade", cidade1);

                EditText etEditora= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etEditora);
                String editora = etEditora.getText().toString();
                intent.putExtra("etEditora", editora);

                EditText etAnoLivro= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etAnoLivro);
                String ano = etAnoLivro.getText().toString();
                intent.putExtra("etAnoLivro", ano);

                startActivity(intent);          
            }           
        });         
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
    }   
}
```

Classe `FormatacaoLivro`:

```
public class FormatacaoLivro extends Activity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.formatacao_livro);

        TextView tvFormatacaoLivro = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvFormatacaoLivro);
        Intent intent = getIntent();

        String autor1 = intent.getStringExtra("etAutor1");
        String[] a1= autor1.split(" ");
        String a1pronto = a1[1].toUpperCase()+","+a1[0];

        String autor2 = intent.getStringExtra("etAutor2");
        String[] a2= autor2.split(" ");
        String a2pronto = a2[1].toUpperCase()+","+a2[0];

        String autor3 = intent.getStringExtra("etAutor3");
        String[] a3= autor3.split(" ");
        String a3pronto = a3[1].toUpperCase()+"."+a3[0];

        String titulo1 = intent.getStringExtra("etTitulo1");
        String edicao1 = intent.getStringExtra("etEdicao");
        String cidade1 = intent.getStringExtra("etCidade");
        String editora = intent.getStringExtra("etEditora");
        String ano = intent.getStringExtra("etAnoLivro");

        String ref = a1pronto+";"+a2pronto+";"+a3pronto+","+titulo1+","+edicao1+","+cidade1+","+editora+","+ano;
        /*Log.i("aula", ref);*/
        tvFormatacaoLivro.setText(ref); 
    }
}
```

Imagem do erro: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JzGQ3.jpg

Comment: Quando esse erro aparece, no log do seu sistema aparece uma pilha de exceções. Publique essa pilha aqui para que possamos entender melhor o problema.

Comment: Do console ou do LogCat?

Comment: LogCat @FelipeDeAquinoNascimento

Comment: http://pastebin.com/QQSxQ9mZ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Me parece um problema com algum desses seus acessos a índice 1, como em

```
    String autor1 = intent.getStringExtra("etAutor1");
    String[] a1= autor1.split(" ");
    String a1pronto = a1[1].toUpperCase()+","+a1[0];
```

Já que o seu erro é:

```
02-01 12:02:51.219: E/AndroidRuntime(2103): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{si.uemg.appformatadorabnt/si.uemg.appformatadorabnt.FormatacaoLivro}:
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1
```

Isso significa que provavelmente um dos seus `"autorN"` não possui duas palavras, o que faz com que o `split(" ")` retorne apenas um componente (daí o índice 1 não existe). Sugiro que verifique esses dados que vêm dos extras do Intent e garanta que são válidos, ou mude sua lógica de tratamento desses casos.

Comment: Então mudei a lógica de tratamento desses casos, mas o erro persiste. http://pastebin.com/iSKC0FnK

Comment: Pode atualizar a pergunta com o log do novo erro?

Comment: Claro. http://pastebin.com/yX8zsXsq

Comment: Seu log parece estar mostrando erros de momentos diferentes (a julgar pelos horários). Provavelmente erros separados. Pode isolar apenas o erro que está acontecendo agora?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/XB2KUPuX

Comment: Me parece que seu erro mudou. Agora é `ComponentInfo{si.uemg.appformatadorabnt/si.uemg.appformatadorabnt.FormatacaoLivro}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference` . Isso provavelmente significa que algum dos seus ids para `EditText` ou `TextView` não são válidos ou não existem na tela atual.

Comment: A tela onde estou setando os dados http://pastebin.com/uUdLYUYz                 E o AndroidManifest.xml estão todas as activities registradas, realmente não entendo porque tá dando isso =/////

Comment: Seu layout se chama `campos_livro` mas você está chamando ele de `formatacao_livro` no seu código.

Comment: Então ai eu quero pegar todos o conteúdo que o usuário digitar desse campos_livro e mandar as informações formatadas pra uma outra activity que é essa formatacao_livro que contém um TextView chamado tvFormatacaoLivro

Comment: Mas você tem que passar esses dados através do Bundle, como estava fazendo no código inicial. Não pode pegar eles diretamente da outra activity com o findViewById, porque os ids não existem para a outra tela.

Comment: Como posso fazer isso para que apareça tudo que o usuário digitou pra uma outra activity? Pode me dar sugestões de solução por código pra eu poder visualizar o problema?

Comment: Você já estava passando tudo no código inicial, pelo que entendi. O problema é que alguns dados não tinham duas palavras, e você presumia isso no seu split. Verifique por que esses dados estão inconsistentes. Seu problema é os dados, não o algoritmo. Se tem alguma dúvida sobre passagem de parâmetros via Bundle, crie uma nova pergunta sobre isso, pois já estamos indo pra outro rumo aqui.

Comment: Deu certo aqui. Em breve postarei na Google Play :)

Comment: Parabéns :) . Não se esqueça de aceitar a resposta, caso tenha ajudado.